# How to change specify previous clicked image button view when the 2nd click button is occur

Tags: android

I have doubt in when I click the 2nd time image button, I want to change the both button image view in simultaneously.

Example:
1. first time press the button 1 and change already the first time image view. (get work)
2. second time press the other button 2 and I want change image view for the both button 1 and 2 in simultaneously. But I can only get the ibutton as variable signal to change the button 2 image view and button 1 can't get.

Question:
1. How do I change the button image view for button 1 when I click the button 2?
2. How do I can keep the button variable in array?

My code like this:

```
public class CheckersTest extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        final ImageView iv_new_game = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.new_game);
        iv_new_game.setOnClickListener(welcome_listener);
    }

    OnClickListener welcome_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            final ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
            if (iv.getId() == R.id.new_game) {
                setContentView(R.layout.checkers_board);

            final ImageButton b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
            final ImageButton b4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
            final ImageButton b6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);

// set the OnClickListeners.

                b2.setOnClickListener(button_listener);
                b4.setOnClickListener(button_listener);
                b6.setOnClickListener(button_listener);

// Re-enable the Click-able property of buttons.

                b2.setClickable(true);
                b4.setClickable(true);
                b6.setClickable(true);
              }
        };
    };


 OnClickListener button_listener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageButton ibutton = (ImageButton) v;

        ibutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_bol);

       }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second Button's `onclick` method get instance of first button and set image.

Comment: Thanks for reply. when I come for 2nd time click the button 2, the button 1 signal I can't get it to change the image button 1.

Comment: IN THE ABOVE CODE YOU ARE USING THE SAME ONCLICK LISTENER FOR ALL BUTTONS

Comment: so, mean that i have to create another all similar as  OnClickListener? got method for keeping the first click ibutton variable in array? so then I can use to manipulate the image view. Thanks you...

Comment: thats right u have to create seperate onl=click listener for each button, accept the answer if its right so that some other users can get a clear picture later.